# split/parse a char array and get value between two tokens C

Tags: c, arrays, split, char

So, after some searching and googling, i can not figure out how to extract a value between two tokens in a char array. here is some of my code:

```
    char *data= (char *) malloc( 50);
    strcpy(data, "123 123 123 abcdef/456->ghijklm/789 123 123");
```

I need to extract "abcdef" as Str1 and "ghijkm" as Str2.

The first solution that everyone recommend is strtok as follow:

```
str1 = strtok(temp, "/");    // str1=abcdef
```

but how about the secound one? i mean str2, so.

Q1: How do i extract ghijkmn as str2?

Q2: Is there any other existing utility function I can leverage? or any other solution to deal with this kind of situation?

[Added:]
What i need is all of strings separated by white spaces. all of "123"s are in desired format except that one is different. I need only two part of it as mentioned above.

Comment: You tagged this [C], but used the `new` keyword, which is C++ only.

Comment: What defines the start of `"abcdef"`?  It is clearly not *space*, because *space* marks the beginning of string '"123"'.  On what basis should we skip over `"123"`, and only match `"abcdef"`?

Comment: 123 is a sample. The delimiter between those strings is white space.

Comment: If you want the first string delimited by whitespace, then it is `"123"`.   So (again), how are you saying the expected result is `"abcdef"`?  Or maybe you want the first 3 strings skipped?  Or maybe you want the first string that ends with a `"/"`?  You have not been clear.

Comment: You should have more examples of that string to establish a pattern (one could be: _some\_junk 1st\_text\_that\_we\_care\_about/some\_numeric\_junk->2nd\_text\_that\_we\_care\_about/some\_other\_junk_).

Comment: What you need is an alphabetic character string or a character string between the characters you specify E.g(Between `'>'` and `'/'`)?

Comment: @abelenky what i need is all of strings separated by white spaces. all of "123"s are in desired format except that one is different. I need only two part of it as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you want all the strings and just some part of one of them,  you can use the following piece of code if and only if the location of '*abcdef/456->ghijklm/789*' in ***data*** array is fixed:

```
                //data ="123 123 123 123 123 123 123" abcdef/456->ghijklm/789 123");
                char temp[/*strlen(data)*/];
                char temp2[/*strlen(data)*/];
                char *splitPtr, *p, *abcdef, *ghijklm, _789;
                splitPtr = data;
                splitCounter = 0;
                for (char *p = strtok_r(data, " ", &splitPtr); p; p = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &splitPtr)) {
                    if (splitCounter == _the_location_of_special_text) {
                        strcpy(temp, p);                        
                        abcdef = strtok(temp, "/");
                        char *gt = strchr(p, '>')+1;
                        int index = (int)(gt - p);                        
                        strcpy(temp2, p+index);

                        ghijklm = strtok(temp2, "/");

                        _789 = strrchr( p, '/' )+1;
                    }
                    else {
                    //use the p as 123
                         }
                    splitCounter += 1;
                }
                printf ("Part 1: %s\n,Part 2: %s\n,Part 3: %s\n", abcdef, ghijklm , _789);
```

The output:

Part 1: abcdef

Part 2: ghijklm

Part 3: 789

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *between(const char *str, char start, char end){
//return between start and end. However, start and end are not included.
    const char *s = NULL, *e;
    if(!str || !*str) return NULL;
    if((e = strchr(str+1, end)) == NULL)
        return NULL;//end character not found
    for(int i = e-str-1; i >= 0; --i){
        if(str[i] == start){
            s = str + i + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!s)
        return between(e, start, end);//start character not found
    int len = e - s;
    char *ret = malloc(len + 1);
    if(ret){
        memcpy(ret, s, len);
        ret[len] = 0;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(void){
    const char *data = "123 123 123 abcdef/456->ghijklm/789 123 123";
    char *str1 = between(data, ' ', '/');

    if(str1){
        printf("str1: '%s'\n", str1);
        char *str2 = between(data, '>', '/');//use strstr+strlen+1 for after str1, or save search position
        if(str2)
            printf("str2: '%s'\n", str2);
        free(str1);free(str2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"However A and B are not included"*, what are A and B?  Not seen in your function.

Comment: @abelenky Thanks,  I fixed that typo.

Answer (score 1):

[IDEOne Code](http://ideone.com/jPEk4d)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    char text[]="123 123 123 abcdef/456->ghijklm/789 123 123";
    char* ptr = strtok(text, " ");
    char* slash;

    char* str1;
    char* str2;

    while(ptr)
    {
        if (slash = strstr(ptr, "/"))
        {
            *slash = '\0';
            str1 = ptr;
            ptr = ++slash;
            break;
        }
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    str2 = strtok(ptr, ">");
    while(ptr)
    {
        if (slash = strstr(ptr, "/"))
        {
            *slash = '\0';
            str2 = ptr;
            break;
        }
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    printf("Found a: %s; and b: %s\n", str1, str2);
    return 0;
}
```

***Output***

```
Found a: abcdef; and b: ghijklm
```

Answer (score 1):

So from what I understand, you just want to extract the fully alphabetic strings from your `char []` array. If this is the case, you can just parse the words using [`strtok`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm), and test if the string has all alphabetic letters using [`isalpha`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isalpha.htm) from `<ctype.h>`.

Something like this could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char data[] = "123 123 123 abcdef/456->ghijklm/789 123 123";
    char *word;
    const char *delim = " /->";
    int i, validlet, strnum = 1;

    word = strtok(data, delim);
    while (word) {
        validlet = 0;
        for (i = 0; word[i]; i++) {
            if (!isalpha(word[i])) {
                break;
            }
            validlet++;
        }
        if (validlet == strlen(word)) {
            printf("Found str %d: %s\n",strnum, word);
            strnum++;
        }
        word = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    return 0;
}
```